# How to align the link to center in HTML

Tags: html

```
<a href = "https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverFlow</a>
```

To align the link to center, what needs to be done, can anyone please let me know

Comment: What have you tried? There are tons of questions just like this, so did you at least search? And which was centered? Horizontally? Vertically? Both?

Comment: a {
  text-align: center;
}. i tried this, i want horizontally centered

Answer (score 1):

To make the link centered, you can do:

```html
<a href = "https://stackoverflow.com/" style = "float: right; width: 100%; text-align: center;">StackOverFlow</a>
```